# splongoperation execution timeout

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

does splongoperation override execution timeout setting value in layouts/web.config,
in sharepoint 2010 farm or standalone as well as sharepoint 2013 standalone?

I have been only noticing different behaviour in sharepoint 2013 farm environment where it does not.

to be specific this tag

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="360" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any issues with SPLongOperation timing out. however have you tried changing the SharepointRoot web.config at \Template\Layouts directory.